# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' Error despite having downloaded Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, spyder

I'd like to build a web scraping tool, and plan on using Selenium to extract information. I downloaded the newest version of Selenium today, and it appears to have downloaded successfully (see second image). However, when I run just the first two lines of code (below this paragraph), I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'".

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

I am currently using Spyder, and have tested multiple interpreters, but to no avail. If you have any idea of where the issue might lie, your help will be greatly appreciated.

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4zPE.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/meQfU.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: dont paste images of text, just post the text